# Javascript - can modify array passed to function only sometimes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

Why does the first function not modify the original array like the second function does?

```
var a= [3, 4, 5];
function doesNothing(a) {
    a=[1,1,1];
}

function doesSomething(a) {
    a.push(6);
}

doesNothing(a);
console.log(a);     // [3,4,5] not [1,1,1]
doesSomething(a);
console.log(a);     //[3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Because all things are passed by value in JS. The argument `a` is a new value. It is not the same `a` as outside the function.

Answer (score 8):

The first function makes no attempt to modify the array. All it does is assign a new value to the parameter that, when it was called, was given a *copy* of a reference to the array. The variable `a` in the first function is just a variable with an object reference as its value. The assignment statement just changes its value, exactly as if your function had

```
    a = 5;
```

instead.

Note that you've declared the first function with `a` as a parameter - that symbol `a` hides the `a` outside the function.

The second function does modify the array because it calls a method on the array object that modifies it.

Answer (score 4):

1. If a is passed into the function as a parameter, it is a local variable, so resetting its value will not affect the outside variable a.
2. But using methods that mutate array will change the outside variable like pop()/shift()/push/splice... and you can also use '.' to mutate the array directly like: `arr.length=0;`; `push()` can have multiple params, so you can: `arr.push(...anotherArray)`.
3. If a is not passed as a parameter, but instead, the function reads it directly from the global scope, resetting value will directly change the variable.
   So, read it directly inside the function, and don't pass it as a parameter. Or pass it as a parameter, but using methods that will mutate the array to change its value.
4. See the examples:
   [pass as a param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXbWE.png)

[read from outside directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6JAn.png)

Answer (score 2):

Because in your first function, the statement `a =` initializes a **new** variable in local scope (it essentially translates to `var a =`) completely unrelated to the global `a` variable, whereas in the second function, you're calling upon and mutating the original array passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a= [3, 4, 5];
function doesNothing() {
    a=[1,1,1];
}

function doesSomething() {
    a.push(6);
}

doesNothing(a);
console.log(a);    
doesSomething(a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Hi prashanth the OP wants to know why that happens not how to fix it

Comment: @Typo I was going to post that but it is already mentioned in other answers

Answer (score -2):

Just inside doesNothing() the local variable `a` points to the same array as the the outer variable `a`. Then you assign a newly created array to the local `a`.

```
function doesNotNothing(a) {
  a[0] = 1;
  a[1] = 1;
  a[2] = 1;
}
```

This affects the contents of the array elements.